# How to disable automatic updates in CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, upgrade

**`CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)`**
/ **`Linux 3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64`**

Last week, I noticed that when I tried to restart, there was an option to `Install Updates & Restart`. I do not recall manually installing any updates.

Because this computer is for work, I would rather not upgrade software where a previous version is crucial for development... Or somehow make a mistake and take a day to fix it.

**PS: If needed, how do I rollback to a point before Update A was installed?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that in Centos 7 yum-cron has nothing to do with the "Install Updates & Restart" prompt. I don't need or want automatic updates too. After some tricky research I discovered this feature is provided by a gnome package "packagekit".

Three solutions:

1. uninstall packagekit altogether (my favourite)
2. disable packagekit from running (see systemctl)
3. find PackageKit.conf (in /etc/PackageKit/ on my system) 
   find WritePreparedUpdates= in the file (last line on my system)

   ```
    set WritePreparedUpdates=false
   ```

restart in all three cases (just to be on the safe side...)

More at:
http://www.itsprite.com/linuxhow-to-disable-packagekit-on-centos-fedora-or-rhel/

Comment: Thank you for the reference, and understanding my question!

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely a package called `yum-cron`. You can removed the package which will remove the cronjobs as well.

If you need to rollback to a point before install...run the following:
`yum history`
find the ID of the action.
`yum history undo ###`

of course sudo if you need to.

Comment: Is there a way to disable auto updates **without** removing cron?

Comment: this won't remove cron all together. it will remove the jobs that are created for auto updating.

Comment: yum-cron was set up as a service in the GCP image I was using - very frustrating. Stopping and disabling it worked, uninstall should work too. You may find some details about it in /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf and in some of the /etc/cron* directories. As Justin said, yum-cron != cron, so no worries stopping/uninstalling it.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting yum history and yum history undo - saved me a lot of trouble!