# Disable Centos Update

Tags: centos, yum, upgrade

I'm relatively new at this. Our system just got updated. (we never ask that)

Now, I need to disable auto-updates on CentOS Server 7.5.1804

I see a relevant question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177943/how-to-disable-automatic-updates-in-centos-7/215653#215653%20here) but my system has no `packagekit`, so the solution does not work for me at least.

What I looking for

**Question 1:**

A way to disable updates but make sure *security updates* for the kernel are available

> ```
> # /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf
> #  What kind of update to use:
> # default                            = yum upgrade
> # security                           = yum --security upgrade
> # security-severity:Critical         = yum --sec-severity=Critical upgrade
> # minimal                            = yum --bugfix update-minimal
> # minimal-security                   = yum --security update-minimal
> # minimal-security-severity:Critical =  --sec-severity=Critical update-minimal
> update_cmd = default
>
> # Whether a message should be emitted when updates are available,
> # were downloaded, or applied.
> update_messages = yes
>
> # Whether updates should be downloaded when they are available.
> download_updates = yes
>
> # Whether updates should be applied when they are available.  Note
> # that download_updates must also be yes for the update to be applied.
> apply_updates = yes
> ```

Do I have to change either of the following

> - download_updates (yes => no)
> - apply_updates (yes => no)
> - update_cmd (default => security)

To achieve that?

**Question 2:**
  If I have to disable an update of the specific packages, do I have to follow the below step?

```
> vi /etc/yum.conf 
> ## Added this inside yum.conf
> exclude=postgresql
```

If yes, how I can I be sure that the package name given is the correct one? (Essentially I want to disable `postgresql`.) 
i.e whether it is `postgresql` or `postgresql-server` or something else

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** add `includepkgs=kernel*` to `yum.conf`. This will make it so that no packages are ever updated except for your kernel packages. It will also prevent installs of packages not beginning with the kernel, so make sure you've installed everything you need to install before adding this line. Alternatively, you can add this line to individual repo files, and it will only affect that `repo`.

**Question 2:** add `exclude=postgresql*` in the same way as `includepkg`. This will make it so no packages whose names begin with `postgresql` can be installed or updated.

Comment: Setting `update_cmd=security` will also work, right?

Comment: You will want to set `update_cmd=security` as you write, yes, if your goal is *only security* updates of only the kernel* packages.

Please understand the differences between updates in Enterprise Linux and updates in other linux distros.  The risk factor is generally vastly different (although RHEL7/Centos7 are a step back).  Be okay with updates that are as frequent as you want -- I've had a fleet of machines in production auto-updating nightly with no issues caused by packaging ... for 16 years.  It IS possible.